# Java jdk help me!

Tags: java

как всем известно java jdk 8 стала платная, киньте пж ссылку где можно скачать!

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что явно не по теме

Answer (score 3):

Это неправда. JDK стало платной только для корпоративного использования. Разработчики на своих компьютерах могут использовать его бесплатно. Скачать можно на официальном сайте.

Помимо этого, для любых целей бесплатно можно использовать все версии, вышедшие до 16 апреля 2019 года, а также Open JDK с любой датой выхода.

Подробнее на хабре: https://habr.com/ru/post/448632/

PS: Здесь не то место, где можно просить ссылки на пиратские версии.

Comment: Статейка на Хабре не очень качественная. [Эта](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244) лучше.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, возможно, но я её впервые вижу. К тому же она на английском. Можешь написать отдельный ответ, если там есть какая-то ещё существенная информация, а то мне статью читать лень.

Comment: Да не, ответ нормальный.