# Версии Java: платные - не платные, что вообще происходит?

Tags: java, openjdk

Если я разрабатываю на Spring MVC web приложение, какую версию Java мне взять, для проекта, который планируется запустить в интернет с целью заработка и чтобы не платить при этом Oracle?

Раньше все было просто: качал последнюю версию и ни о чем не задумывался.

После продолжительного перерыва в Java я зашел по старинке на сайт, скачал последнюю доступную версию Java, коей оказалась jdk 12.0.1.

Но тут я начинаю узнавать, что есть какие-то сборки OpenJDK, Oracle JDK, что начиная с 1.8 что-то поменялось. Oracle какое-то лицензирование ввело.

Можете кратко объяснить, какую взять версию Java для разработки сайта на Spring MVC, на котором планируется зарабатывать на рекламе и возможно в отдаленном будушем на платных подписках(т.е. планируется коммерческий продукт), чтобы при этом не заморачивать себе голову с лицензированием?

Comment: openjdk всю дорогу открытая и бесплатная...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985543/178988

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Язык Java и виртуальная машина HotSpot - это open source. Есть абсолютно бесплатный [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/) в который [контрибьютят множество других компаний](https://db.openjdk.java.net/people), кроме Oracle - от небольших типа Excelsior JET до гигантов типа IBM. Oracle JDK собирается из исходного кода Open JDK. Они полностью идентичны. Деньги Oracle берёт за поддержку собственной сборки. Так же, как у Red Hat есть платная поддержка бесплатного Линукса. Если вам поддержка не нужна, используйте [одну из множества бесплатных сборок OpenJDK](https://jdk.dev) и живите спокойно. Если вы компания класса MailRu Group, предоставляющая высоконагруженные сервисы 330 миллионам пользователей, и ваши специалисты каждую неделю находят баг в виртуальной машине, лучше использовать платный Oracle JDK.

Подробное официальное заявление на эту тему можно прочитать [здесь](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244).

Comment: Другими словами, [вот это](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) скачивать не нужно, а [вот это](https://jdk.java.net/12/) - нужно?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия можете скачивать и то и то. Но вы не должны использовать Oracle JDK если пишите проекты для бизнеса. По крайне мере, использовать бесплатно. А вообще, в плане функциональности это практически одно и то же.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия тоже так понял и перекачал себе Java, чтобы не морочить дальше себе голову. По крайней мере по второй ссылке вроде сообщается, что это _GNU General Public License, version 2, with the Classpath Exception._

Answer (score 1):

OpenJDK - абсолютно бесплатен, но его надо обновлять каждые 6 месяцев в сентябре и марте (выходят новые версии).

Comment: обновлять? кому надо?

Comment: Я почти уверен, что нужно обновлять версию **openjdk** (!) каждые полгода, т.к. при выходе новой версии, завершается поддержка старой...

Comment: но работать то она от этого не перестаёт. а вот от смены jdk в целом ничего хорошего ждать не приходится, в боевом проекте смена jdk - большой стресс для программистов и билд инженеров

Comment: Но для коммерческого использования она вроде больше не годиться, опять же, насколько я знаю. Для стартапов на несколько часов остановить сервера - не проблема, но для крупных организаций лучше купить Oracle JDK и долгосрочную поддержку.

Comment: oracle jdk имеет закрытый исходный код, любой проект где нужна государственная сертификация кода, нуждается в исходных кодах jdk

Comment: Смотря чью сборку вы используете. Минорные обновления для билдов OpenJDK от Oracle только раз в квартал и не более двух для каждой мажорной версии Java. Но Red Hat, например, до сих пор поддерживает даже Open JDK 6. И не только секьюрити фиксы выпускает, но и фичи бэкпортит.